# std::unordered_map with custom value type, operator[]

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl, unordered-map

I'm trying to use std::unordered_map, as shown in [the example here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator[]).

```
class CSVRecord {
public:
    CSVRecord(string csvLine) : _fields(vector<string>()) {...}
    vector<string> _fields; 
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    unordered_map<string, CSVRecord> m;
    CSVRecord rec = CSVRecord("test");
    m["t"] = rec;
    return 0;
}
```

However, `m["t"] = rec`  gives an [error](http://pastebin.com/3MeKc1VK): `no matching function for call to ‘CSVRecord::CSVRecord()’`.

I used `m.insert(pair<string, CSVRecord>("t",rec))` instead, but I wonder why the original didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting this error because of lack of default constructor in your CSVRecord.

How does `operator[]` work?

`operator[]` searches for the key provided to it and if element is already there in map it returns the reference to that element. If element is not there then it adds the key with default constructed object. In your case it was not able to find appropriate constructor hence emitted error.

Comment: Thanks, so adding elements using `operator[]` isn't recommended because of the extra copy, right?

Comment: @Dimid: it's a convenient notation, and default-construction/copying can often be elided by the optimiser - there's very rarely a need to avoid `[]` but as always profile truly performance-critical code and see where the measurement leads you.